# How to do MAVEN filtering in this case?

Tags: java, maven

I have maven project which contains Java classes and Windows/Linux scripts. Whenever I made some changes to the Java source code, I then execute 'mvn install' and call those scripts to test my changes. Those scripts therefore points to Maven repository to find the JARs. For instance,

```
SET app=%M2_REPO%\A\B\C\1.0-SNAPSHOT\C-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
SET app1=%M2_REPO%\E\F\G\1.0-SNAPSHOT\G-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
java -classpath !app!;!app1!;!app2!;!app3! !main_class! %1 %2 %3 %4
```

Now, the requirement is to
1. package all the jars and scripts into one ZIP file;
2. jars and scripts have to be at the root level in this ZIP file.

I just wonder if it is possible to automatically set app at

```
app=%M2_REPO%\A\B\C\1.0-SNAPSHOT\C-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

at compile phase

and automatically change it to

```
app=C-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

at install phase.

If yes then how? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you setting the classpath manually like that? Why not use the Maven assembly plugin to generate an executable JAR + package up everything in a ZIP?

Comment: I recommend to use [appassembler-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/) to generate such scripts for linux/windows and don't craft them yourself.

Comment: you can use filtering on a script, laucnhed by maven but it's bad bad bad. I prefer the way of @LOUDKING

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use maven-resources-plugin with two separate setting files at two different phases:

```
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>compile-settings</id>
        <phase>process-resources</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>something</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
            </resources>
            <filters>
                <filter>resources/compile.properties</filter>
            </filters>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
        <id>package-settings</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>something</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
            </resources>
            <filters>
                <filter>resources/package.properties</filter>
            </filters>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```